# Creating named-ranges using formula or VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet containing data in about 800,000 rows, with three columns.

Here are a few rows:
[image]

I am looking for a way to automate the defining of named-ranges. There will be around 110 named ranges in my sheet, which I will use in Index formulas.

Is there a formula (or VBA) that will create a named-range (Define Named Range) for each of the rows and columns based on the group nr (column C) in my sheet?

Excel-Define-Named-Ranges
[image]

For example, all rows in Group1 (for cols A, B and C) will get a named-range called "Group1" and so on down to "Group110".

Note, I do not want to manually select the range of rows & columns for each group number using the Define-Named range button in the Ribbon, since each group can have several thousand rows.

Comment: Formulas can only calculate values. Macro=VBA (let's all forget about Excel4 macros). It's not hard to do this with VBA, but what do you expect: That we write the code for you? That's not the idea of SO.

Answer (score 0):

A Mix of hand and vba.

Make a listobject of your List.

Then you can filter one by one the group and use a makro:

```
Sub JustAnIdea()
    Dim l As ListObject
    Set l = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    Dim ra As Range
    Set ra = l.DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible)
    Dim theName As String
    theName = ra.Cells(1, 3).Value
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add theName, ra
    End Sub
```

Should be less than 10 min.
You could automate the filter, but I think this would take more time than doing it by hand.